# Arduino does not detect the rising edge of a square wave signal at 50Hz

Tags: c, arduino, signals, interrupt, edge-detection

I would like to detect all rising edges of a square wave signal and output them via the seriel monitor.  I am using an Arduino UNO for this, which is supposed to detect the edge using an interrupt pin. The signal comes from a signal generator (the signal is adjustable (50Hz would be desirable).  I have written this code below, but it does not work, because if I set the frequency and start the code, for example at f=1Hz 20 interrupts are triggered!

Can someone please enlighten me how and which method I should use to achieve such operation with Arduino?

Thanks in advance.

```
    volatile int counter = 0;
    const int interruptPin = 2;
   

    void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), interrupt_call, CHANGE);

    }
    void interrupt_call() {

     counter++;

    }

    void loop() {
       if(counter){
         Serial.println(counter);
         counter=0;
       }else{
         Serial.println(counter);
       }
     }
```

Comment: At what frequency is your `loop` function executed? I would assume the loop is faster than sending your counter via UART.

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? What values does it output, and when?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "but it does not work, because if I set the frequency and start the code, for example at f=1Hz 20 interrupts are triggered!" i would've thought you start the code at 50hz? Anyway, a tip is that Serial.println() takes a veery long time to complete ~200ms maybe, so that's something to be weary of.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect rising edges, change the following line:

```
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), interrupt_call, CHANGE);
```

To:

```
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), interrupt_call, RISING);
```

Don't print the counter variable when it's zero, so remove the following lines from your `loop` function:

```
   }else{
     Serial.println(counter);
```

Your interrupt pin may be floating. Did you configure it as an input pin? Add the following line in your `setup` function, before the line containing `attachInterrupt()`:

```
pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

Now, you should see the number of rising edges that happened during the period of your `loop` function.
Set it to a high value (for instance, 10 seconds) and see if you get about 10 for your 1 Hz square wave. If it doesn't work, post the `main` function/complete code here as well.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help! I have corrected all my mistakes. Unfortunately, now the same error is output. I posted the output as an image here. What is the reason for this? That the interrupt goes through ?

[image]
volatile int counter = 0;
const int interruptPin = 3;

```
void setup() {

 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
 attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), interrupt_call, 
 RISING);

 }
 void interrupt_call() {
   counter++;
 }

 void loop() {
   if(counter){
    Serial.println(counter);

    counter=0;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick reply. I meant that if I set the frequency of the signal generator to 1Hz and then start the code, a rising edge from the interrupt is detected in the several times per period, but actually the interrupt may only trigger once per time period and output in Serielen Monitor. I have uploaded my output as an image. I would be very grateful for a tip or an idea.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqoIj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I thought the part of your code calling the `loop` function was missing, but I've just realized that for the typical arduino code the delay must be inserted in the `loop` function itself.

So you can add it by appending `delay(1000)` to the `loop` function, so it becomes:

```
void loop()
{
    if (counter) {

        Serial.println(counter);
        counter=0;
    }

    delay(1000);
}
```

In this example, the loop will have a period of `1000` ms. So you should see the number of rising edges (if any) that occurs in one second now, instead of printing "1" every time it occurs.

Note that you can provide more information for your problem by editing your question instead of adding another answer.